# Is it right to say “I keep telling my mom even though she is sleep”?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it right to say:

> I keep telling my mom even though she  is sleep

I don’t know if it soun weird or unnatural to say it by the grammarical structure

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say.  You can say "My mom is **asleep**" or "My mom **is sleeping**", but even if you fix that I don't understand why you would be talking to your mother while she is sleeping.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Perrie. As Andrew has pointed out, *sleep* should probably be *asleep*. If you correct this, the sentence would be grammatically correct. It sounds unnatural to be telling something to somebody who is asleep. Is there anything else in particular that makes you think that this sentence is unnatural.

Comment: Sorry, it likes texting.

Comment: Probably you want - I keep telling my mom even though she is *asleep.*

Answer (score 1):

Purely on its own, the sentence makes no sense.

You keep telling her *what*?

> I keep telling my mom **that**, even though she is asleep.

This sentence is grammatical (note that I added a comma and changed **sleep** to **asleep**), even though it's missing context. (There would need to be a previous sentence that defines what it is you are telling her.)

> I keep **speaking to** my mom, even though she is asleep.

This, too, is grammatical. Also, the sentence on its own makes more sense than the other versions of the sentence.

Comment: I don't think that **that** is essential in this sentence. It is quite common, especially in informal speech, to not specify what is being told within the actual sentence, as long as what's being told was made clear in a previous sentence. Here is an example from Merriam-Webster: “What is his name?” “I don't know. He didn't tell me.” https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell

Comment: @JavaLatte - I had the same thought, although, to be fair, this answer does start with: _Purely on its own..._ So I think Jason realizes how, with the right surrounding context, the “that” could be left omitted.

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, context would play a big role in explaining the reference—even without **that**, in some cases. If there had been a previous sentence provided, my answer would have changed somewhat. ;)